# SPSS aggergate on 2 variables

Tags: aggregate, spss

I am trying to compute a N_break that has to "satisfy" a condition. I have a variable which indicates 1 or 0. Lets call that variable "HT". Every lopnr is also labled in every row multiple times. So first 10 rows can be ID nr 1. And next 20 can be ID nr 2 and so on.

My question is: How do i create a N-break with lopnr as breakvariable that has to have HT=1? I am not allowed to select only 1s on variable HT before, since i need the 0s in the file.

Comment: What is a "lopnr"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few simple ways to do this:
1 - USE FILTER

```
filter cases by HT.
aggregate ....
```

when you get back to original dataset, use:

```
filter off.
use all.
```

2 - COPY DATASET

```
dataset name orig.
dataset copy foragg.
dataset activate foragg.
select if HT.
aggregate....
```

3 - TEMPORARY SELECTION

```
temporary.
select if HT.
aggregate....
```